# What are the main differences between APEX and Java

Tags: apex, java

What are the main differences and is it possible to switch between these to languages. I`ve made some searches in google and i know that they are quite similar but ....I decide to make a post here bacause i want some real experienced opinions.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Inner classes and interfaces can only be declared one level deep
  inside an outer class.
- Static methods and variables can only be declared in a top-level
  class definition, not in an inner class.
- Inner classes behave like static Java inner classes, but do not
  require the static keyword. Inner classes can have instance member
  variables like outer classes, but there is no implicit pointer to an
  instance of the outer class (using the this keyword).
- The private access modifier is the default, and means that the method
  or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it is
  defined. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or
  variable is private.
- Specifying no access modifier for a method or variable and the
  private access modifier are synonymous.
- The public access modifier means the method or variable can be used
  by any Apex in this application or namespace.
- The global access modifier means the method or variable can be used
  by any Apex code that has access to the class, not just the Apex code
  in the same application. This access modifier should be used for any
  method that needs to be referenced outside of the application, either
  in the SOAP API or by other Apex code. If you declare a method or
  variable as global, you must also declare the class that contains it
  as global.
- Methods and classes are final by default. The virtual definition
  modifier allows extension and overrides. The override keyword must be
  used explicitly on methods that override base class methods.
- Interface methods have no modifiers—they are always global.
- Exception classes must extend either exception or another
  user-defined exception.Their names must end with the word
  exception.Exception classes have four implicit constructors that are
  built-in, although you can add others.
- Classes and interfaces can be defined in triggers and anonymous
  blocks, but only as local.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now i have some vision about differences between apex and java. Is it possible easily to switch between apex and java ?

Comment: Yeah. You can easily switch between Apex and Java because their syntax is quite similar. Refer: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

If you got the answer, please mark the answer is correct.

Comment: APEX is object oriented programming language as JAVA is not it ?

Comment: Apex is a strongly-typed, object-oriented programming language.